# In a Wordpress plugin, why doesn't `register_rest_route()` work when called in the activation hook?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have this (example) plugin:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Great Plugin
*/

function hello() {
    return 'Hello, world!';
}

function my_great_plugin_init() {
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
        register_rest_route( 'great-plugin/v1', '/hello', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'hello',
        ) );
    } );
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_great_plugin_init');
?>
```

When I activate this plugin, the `/wp-json/great-plugin/v1/hello` route does not exist. However, if I move the `add_action` call to the top level, like so:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Great Plugin
*/

function hello() {
    return 'Hello, world!';
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route( 'great-plugin/v1', '/hello', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'hello',
    ) );
} );
?>
```

then the `/wp-json/great-plugin/v1/hello` route exists and responds to `GET` requests with `"Hello, world!"`. Why doesn't the endpoint get registered when the registration happens during the activation hook?

Comment: Is `register_rest_route` supposed to permanently store this somewhere? If not, and this works like most of the rest of hooks etc. in WP, then you have registered that route _only_ during the process of activating your plugin, for that one single request.

Answer (score 2):

if you check the WordPress Codex your will find that `register_activation_hook` run only when the plugin is activated

> When a plugin is activated, the action 'activate_PLUGINNAME' hook is called.

[Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook)

Using `register_rest_route` inside that hook will not work because `register_rest_route` is called when the `rest_api_init`as mentioned in  [WP REST API Doc](https://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/)s

> We do this through a function called register_rest_route, which should be called in a callback on rest_api_init to avoid doing extra work when the API isn’t loaded.

so basically when you put `rest_api_init` inside  `register_activation_hook` that will not triggered  after the plugin is activated.

in another word when the `rest_api_init` is initiated it will not detect your hook

> Actions are the hooks that the WordPress core launches at specific points during execution, or when specific events occur. Plugins can specify that one or more of its PHP functions are executed at these points, using the Action API.

[Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)

I hope that make sense.

If you need an more explanation let me know.

Comment: More guidance on why rest_api_init is the correct hook to use can be found in the announcement that using other hooks will raise a notice in WordPress 5.1 https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/01/11/new-rest-api-notice-in-5-1/